# Form input type php

Tags: php, html, forms, types

I want to create a form using a table where a column generates the questions( nom ) and another one generates the type of the response(type ) that can be  (text, date, checkbox, radio etc ...), I was able to generate the questions however I wasn't able to determinate the type.
I am really struggling to use the type column in my champs table as a variable of input types in a form.[image]

Any help would be extremely appreciated

to clarify more here are my codes:

**ChampsModel.php**

```html
<?php 
require_once("../config/database.php");

function Champsbyqid($qid){
 $c = Database :: connect();
 $results = array();
 $q = $c -> prepare ("SELECT nom FROM champs WHERE qid=?") ;
 $q -> execute (array($qid));
 while ($data = $q -> fetch()) {
  $results[] = $data;
 } 
 Database :: disconnect();
 return $results;
}

function getType($qid){
 $c = Database :: connect();
 $results = array();
 $q = $c -> prepare ("SELECT type FROM champs WHERE qid=?") ;
 $q -> execute (array($qid));
 while ($data = $q -> fetch()) {
  $results[] = $data;
 } 
 Database :: disconnect();
 return $results;
}


?>
```

**ChampsController.php**

```html
<?php 
require_once("../model/champsModel.php");

$champs = Champsbyqid(1);
$type = getType(1);

?>
```

**Champs.php**

```html
   <?php
require_once("../controller/champsController.php");

foreach ($champs as $value) {
 foreach ($types as $val) {
  echo $value['nom'].'<form method="POST"><input type='$val['type']'></form>';
 }
 
}


?>  

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating each question repeatedly for every type retrieved, you don't need the second `foreach` loop. I would also suggest using a single query to fetch both values, then you can simple use `$value['nom']` and `$value['type']`. But if you need to keep them separate, just use

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($champs); $i++) {
  echo $champs[$i]['nom'].'<form method="POST"><input type='$type[$i]['type']'></form>';
}
```

Comment: Beat you by a minute... haha.

Comment: vbudo & inarilo thank you both I finally noticed that there is no need for two sql queries and a mixed one was more effective and both your ideas worked thank you very much you don't know how much this is helpful to me thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you're going to want to SELECT * FROM  WHERE qid =  ORDER BY ordre; <-- is this a type that is suppose to be order?.  Get the rows as an associative array, in a variable, lets say $value.  Then,

```
<form method="" action="">
while (there are rows) {

    echo $value["nom"].'<input type="'.$value["type"].'" 
    name="whatever"><br />';

   }
</form>
```

Be weary of reserved words in your programming languages.  Some words you can't use as variables.